# Need help making a sticky Nav bar on scroll - using jade and stylus in nodejs/express

Tags: jquery, html, css, pug, stylus

Here is the code that's in my body section:

```
header.main-header
  h1 Reshared
  p This site is still under construction.
nav.main-nav
  ul
      li
        a(href="#") About
      li
        a(href="#") Services
      li
        a(href="#") Contact
.main
  h2 This is a Column
  p This is a test
```

Here is the code in the main.styl file. I would of also added in an image but of what the site looks like now but I cant at the moment because I need 10 reputation points.

```
@import 'nib'

global-reset()

*
  box-sizing border-box

body
  font-size 16px
  font-family arial, sans-serif

.main-header
  background #f07057
  height 100vh
  position fixed
  width 100%
  top 0
  text-align center
  color #f7f7f7
  display flex
  align-items center
  justify-content center
  flex-direction column

  h1
    font-size 2em

body
  padding-top calc(100vh - 5em)

.main-nav
  background #f7f7f7
  height 80px
  z-index 50
  border-bottom #f07057 5px solid
  text-align center
  display flex
  align-items center
  justify-content center

  li
    display inline

  a
    text-decoration none
    color #111
    font-family arial, sans-serif
    padding 20px
    font-size 20px

.main-nav, .main
   position relative
.main
   background #f2f2e8
```

From what I have how do I go about making my nav sticky ounce the user scrolls past it.

Here is an image of what the site looks like:
[image: This is what the site looks like.]

Here is what happens when the user scrolls down. I than want the nav bar to stick to the top when it hits past it.
[image: Scrolling the site down]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding `static: top` to the navigation bar should do the trick. Then, you should add a top margin to the main page so no content hides under the navbar.